# Migrating drives from Dell PERC 6I/R to PERC 6I

Tags: raid, migration, dell, sas, dell-perc

My Dell PERC 6I/R controller (LSI UCS-61) with two drives in a RAID 1 configuration just died.

I have another server with a PERC 6I controller. Is there any way I could connect the two drives to the working controller and restore the VD without losing data?

I have no Dell support for these servers and I can't seem to enter the right magic phrase into Google to get this information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly try what you're proposing and expect it will likely work. The alternate controller should recognize the RAID data on the drives and warn you of a "foreign configuration". You'll want to follow the prompts during boot to "import" the foreign config, or get into the PERC BIOS with Ctrl + R to import it. 
There's a chance importing won't work if the firmware versions on the two cards are too far apart, but it's unlikely.

Comment: It DID work just as you described, no problems.